# Как узнать пользователь online или нет?

Tags: python, xmpp

Как узнать пользователь online или нет?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала нужно взять правильный [rfc6121](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6121). Там в 4 пункте описывается понятие онлайн/оффлайн. В подпунктах 4.3.1-4.3.2 описываются конкретные станзы для запроса.

Замечу, что если от контакта не получили подписку (некий аналог авторизации, то есть, если нет в контактлисте), то статусов от него не получите. Да, кстати, в xmpp подписки двусторонние.